# Trying to create column in one table and set its value from another table

Tags: sql

I tried to add a new column to a table in same db, I then tried to copy new column from another table's column.

```
ALTER TABLE [library].[dbo].[Member$]
        add  new_column1 float
        go
        update [library] .[dbo] .[Member$] 
        set new_column1  = select [library].[dbo].Category$ .Category  from  [library] .[dbo] .[Category$]  
        GO
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Category$](
        [CatID] [float] NULL,
        [Category] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
        [BooksLimit] [float] NULL,
        [Period] [float] NULL,
        [FinePerDay] [float] NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
    
    GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Member$](
    [Roll No] [float] NULL,
    [RollNo] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [CatID] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [ExpiryDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [ExpiryReason] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Session] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [new_column] [float] NULL,
    [new_column1] [float] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

But the new_column1 is still null

There are multiple values in Category, but row number in both doesnot match, Is that a problem, If yes then how can I achieve this?

Comment: How many rows do you have in `[Category$]`? If there are more than one you will get an error. If there are `0` you will have `null` in all rows. Your query will only work if you have exactly one row in `[Category$]`.

Comment: insert into [library] .[dbo] .[Category$]  
 ([new_column1])
 values 
 (select [library].[dbo].Category$ .Category  from  [library] .[dbo] .[Category$])  
GO

Comment: there are multiple values in Category , but row number in both doesnot match

Comment: Please update your question with table structures, sample data in both tables and the required result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE [library].[dbo].[Member$] add new_column1 float 
go 
update [library] .[dbo] .[Member$] set 
  new_column1 = 
  (
    select TOP 1 [library].[dbo].[Category$].Category 
    from [library].[dbo].[Category$]
  )
```

**BUT**

Doing so you just assigns the same value to all the rows in table Member$, if you need specific settings for each Member$'s row - try to place proper filtering in the subquery

```
select TOP 1 [library].[dbo].[Category$].Category 
from [library].[dbo].[Category$]
WHERE PLACE_YOUR_FILTER_HERE
```

**like this:**

```
ALTER TABLE [library].[dbo].[Member$] add new_column1 float 
go 
update [library] .[dbo] .[Member$] set 
  new_column1 = 
  (
    select TOP 1 [library].[dbo].[Category$].Category 
    from [library].[dbo].[Category$]
    WHERE [library] .[dbo] .[Member$].CatId = [library].[dbo].[Category$].CatId
  )
```

**BUT, special note**

If you want to use ID for category - better use for it an exact type, such as `int` - because `FLOAT` types family are not exact and thus - harder to compare.

Comment: this only copies first row , is it possible to with insert command

Comment: even with filter , only one value will go to all rows

Comment: Filter can include columns from the updating table - so - it can be different for every row in updating table. CHeck it.

Comment: I'll update an answer to show you how to set different values to updating row

Comment: Updated with example based on your schema with special note